# The 'dictionary' parameter of TermDocumentMatrix does not work in R

Tags: r, text-mining, term-document-matrix

Even though I added the keyword to 'dictionary' as below code, it doesn't extract from the sentence.

#### Sample code

```
library(tm)

data = c('a', 'a b', 'c')
keyword = c('a', 'b')

data = VectorSource(data)
corpus = VCorpus(data)
tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(dictionary = keyword))
```

#### Result of my code above

```
inspect(tdm)

<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 2, documents: 3)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 0/6
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 1
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
Docs
Terms 1 2 3
    a 0 0 0
    b 0 0 0
```

#### Normal result should be as follows:

```
Terms 1 2 3
    a 1 1 0
    b 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the minimum word length to `termFreq` `control`.

```
tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(dictionary = keyword, wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))
as.matrix(tdm)

     Docs
Terms 1 2 3
    a 1 1 0
    b 0 1 0
```

Comment: How can I extract words containing multiple words? For example... `data = c('dog cat', 'dog', 'cat')` `keyword = c('dog cat', 'dog', 'cat')` In this state, I want to extract the keyword 'dog cat'.

Comment: In that case you'll probably need to pass a custom tokenization function to `TermDocumentMatrix`. Ideally, though, you'd use bigram scoring similar to `Gensim`'s `Phraser`, but I don't think it is implemented in R yet

Comment: It seemed simple, but complicated. Thank you.